# Having difficulty with specific Future<T> query and collections with nHibernate.

Tags: nhibernate

For the sake of example, I am removing non-queried and non-essential data just to figure out how to do the initial query here.

I have a model structure like this.

```
class Path {
  Guid Id { get; protected set; }
  IList<Step> Steps { get; set; }
  void AddStep(Step entity) {
    // write up bidirectional association
  }
}
class Step {
  Guid Id { get; protected set; }
  Path Path { get; set; }
  // other data irreleveent
}
```

Now assuming 50000 steps, each with 5000 steps... I do realize I don't want to return all of them at once. But putting a limit on my query fetch isn't my real problem.

Here is the exact query I am attempting to use. I am getting the exception..

> NHibernate.QueryException : duplicate alias: lpStep
>     ----> System.ArgumentException : An item with the same key has already been added.

I'm not entirely sure how to handle this scenario. if I use a flat out `Fetch` on the `Path` query, I get `Select+N` errors from the NHibernate Profiler.

I do have batching enabled - but as far as I am aware, that only really applies to inserts, not retrievals. But in any case I am getting back these errors and not sure how to handle it. Any ideas?

```
using (var Transaction = Session.BeginTransaction()) {

                Path lpPath = null;
                Step lpStep = null;

                var lpPaths = Session.QueryOver<Path>(() => lpPath)
                    .Take(50)
                    .Future<Path>();

                var lpSteps = Session.QueryOver<Step>(() => lpStep)
                    .JoinAlias(() => lpPath.Steps, () => lpStep)
                    .Where(o => o.Path.Id == lpPath.Id)
                    .Take(12)
                    .Future<Step>();

                Transaction.Commit();

                foreach (var path in lpPaths) {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} fetched {1} Steps",
                        path.Id, path.Steps.Count);
                }
            }
```

I basically want to say ..

> Select (50) Paths, also, as a separate select but part of the same trip, Select the first (12) Steps that belong the previously selected Paths.

But if I use a flat out join, I get 110 rows, whereas I expect to have 2 tables, 1 of 50 rows, 1 of 600 rows.

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

mind you, I can do some minor alterations and the query runs, but it isn't 'optimized'. I can get the data I want, but it takes multiple trips and lazy loading. I can optimize the actual `Path` selection easily enough but it is those blasted `Step`s. If I just take a restrictive where clause out of the `lpSteps` query, it just returns the first 12 steps, not returning 12 steps for each query done.

I've looked at some of the other stack overflow posts on `Future<T>` and found them to look a lot like this. So I don't understand why it isn't working. I suspect that what is going on is this..

> **lpPaths** runs.
>
> **lpSteps** tries to run, first one succeeds.
>
> **lpSteps** then tries to run again, finds it cannot redefine lpPaths.
>
> **Apocolypse**

I'm really hoping someone smarter than me can enlighten me on the absolute most optimal way to write this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i cant really understand what your use case is. why do you only need the first 12 Steps of each Path? What about batches of Steps to process

```
IList<Guid> pathIds;
while ((pathIds = QueryOver.For<Path>()
     .Where(...)
     .Projection(path => path.Id)
     .SetmaxResults(100)).Count > 0)
{

    int batch = 0;
    const int batchsize = 600;
    IList<Step> steps;
    while ((steps = Session.QueryOver<Step>()
        .Where(step => step.Path.Id).In(pathIds)
        .Where(step => step. ...)
        .SetFirstResult(batch * batchsize)
        .Take(batchsize)
        .List<Step>()).Count > 0)
    {
        DoSomething(steps);
        batch++;
    }
}
```

Comment: The 12 was an arbitrary number to simply represent that I need to be able to select a limited number.

Comment: Well, this approach does take just the rows needed, but it doesn't bring them forward in the actual model returned, so when something iterates over the `Path.Steps` it still ends up lazy loading them...

Comment: Well, I went back to this again and tried some more things, so let me see if I understand what you are suggesting exactly. You are saying I should `[A]` Perform a Projection for my `Path.Id` collection, then `[B]` just do queries based on those ids? This __does__ get me the desired tables in a clean and efficient manner, but how do I go about wiring that up so that I am not affected by the Lazy Loading of accessing the `Path.Steps`?

Comment: @Stacey i dont think NHibernate knows that all steps for a given Path is already loaded after several batches. It always has to ask the Db to know that it knows all steps for a Path. I cant think  right now for a solution to get both paged data and full Path-objects in on step. to prevent lazy loading the best way i know of is `QueryOver.For<Path>().Fetch(p => p.Steps)`;